# Purpose of parentheses around expressions joined by logical "and"

Tags: c#, c

Some coders will wrap each condition in its own parentheses, like this:

Style #1:

```
bool Test(string a, string b)
{
    return ((a != null) && (b != null));
}
```

Style #2:

```
bool Test(string a, string b)
{
    return a != null && b != null;
}
```

In C# the difference is purely stylistic (at least, I think so).  The first expression evaluates first, and the second expression evaluates only if the first is true (otherwise it short-circuits because the entire expression is already confirmed false).

Someone mentioned that #1 above is an "old C style".  What is its practical purpose?  Is there any actual difference between the two, or is it some kind of safeguard against typos (like writing `if (true == x)` instead of `if (x == true)`).

Comment: Most people, when pressed and/or woken up at 4am, don't know *all* the operator precedence rules by heart all the time, so a little lexical help goes a long way.

Comment: In this case, the order of operations makes the two statements (and `return a != null && b != null`, without any parentheses) completely identical. All three are valid C as well. I would leave them off in this case, but often it's helpful to leave them for complicated statements or where more than one precedence is involved (so that you don't have to think too hard, especially with the more esoteric precedence rules for operators like `>>` and `%`).

Comment: I always believed it to be because people learn BODMAS in mathematics before ever learning programming so do it to ensure order of execution as this is what they first learnt

Comment: @Sayse: What is BODMAS? Edit: Oh, seems like a precedence mnemonic.

Comment: [BODMAS](http://www.mathsisfun.com/operation-order-bodmas.html) - (Apologies for confusion)

Comment: @KerrekSB sure, but is there any real case where something inside the parentheses would make a difference between including or omitting them?  I can't think of any (for C#) at the moment.

Comment: I typically use them to group things together in more complicated operations. i.e. `var continue = ((user.IsAuthenticated && user.IsAdmin) && db.IsOpen)`

Comment: @McGarnagle Sure, it can matter.  `1 + 2 * 3` is different from `(1 + 2) * 3`.  The you can imagine that parenthesis are added automatically by the compiler based on the operator precedence rules.  if you add them in according to the same rules, it's not changing the function of the code.  If you don't follow those rules when adding your parenthesis, you change the functionality of the code.

Comment: @Servy I guess an analogue to what I'm asking would be `1 + (2 * 3)`:  why use the parentheses there, when the implied meaning should be intuitive?  Same with an and-joined sequence of conditions (assuming no or/ternary/assignment operators, which muddy the waters).  I understand defensive/explicit coding, but this case seems so overly defensive to me, that I wondered if there was some other reason for using it.

Comment: @McGarnagle How about `(a || b && c || d)`. That's not the same as `((a || b) && (c || d))`

Comment: @McGarnagle: For a real difference, consider `decltype(x)` vs `decltype((x))` in C++...

Comment: @Sayse: Remember that *precedence* and *order of evaluation* have **nothing whatsoever** to do with each other in C.  If you say `A() + B() * C()` then the calls to `A()`, `B()` and `C()` can happen in *any order*. The compiler could for instance choose to do `C()` first, then `A()`, then `B()`, then multiply the first and third results together and add them to the second.  In C# and Java again, **precedence has no relationship to execution order**; in those languages execution order is **left to right**.  `A()`, then `B()`, then `C()`, then the multiplication, then the addition.

Comment: well actually... take 2 sample expressions. Make sure they would both fail at compile time ( types, type mismatch of whatever other reason ) the compiler will yield the 2nd expression first like if the code was being checked from back to front...

Comment: @Sayse Also referred to as PEMDAS in the parts of the world where `(` is called a parenthesis (all of math, too?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is just defensive coding so the writer of the code (and more importantly, future readers) do not have any doubts about the intent and function of the code.

A long time ago I spent many tedious evenings working through code with a colleague who refused to bracket terms due to his unfailing belief in his ability to remember precedence rules. Despite many examples to the contrary. Even when you know those rules yourself it is easier to read code where the intent is crystal clear, rather than double-checking every time.